# go routine, function executed out of desired order

Tags: go

Hi I'm learning goroutine, and I have a question I have a code where I have a publisher and a listener, I need the subscribe call to happen first then the publish call.

```
useCase := New(tt.fields.storage)

            tt.fields.wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                ch, _, err := useCase.Subscribe(tt.args.ctx, tt.args.message.TopicName)
                message, ok :=  <- ch
                if !ok {
                    close(ch)
                    tt.fields.wg.Done()
                }

                require.NoError(t, err)
                assert.Equal(t, tt.want, message)
            }()

            err := useCase.Publish(tt.args.ctx, tt.args.message)
            tt.fields.wg.Wait()
```

and as I send messages inside these two functions I need Go Func, how would I get subscribe to always execute first, and then publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a channel:

```
subscribed:=make(chan struct{})
go func() {
   ch, _, err := useCase.Subscribe(tt.args.ctx, tt.args.message.TopicName)
   if err!=nil {
    ...
   }
   close(subscribed)
   message, ok :=  <- ch
   ...
}()
<-subscribed
err := useCase.Publish(tt.args.ctx, tt.args.message)
```

Comment: i've tested it that way but publish is running first, i need it to run after it's subscribed to the topic.

Comment: Publish will not run until `subscribed` channel is closed, which will happen only after `useCase.Subscribe` returns.

Comment: sorry I ended up making a mistake, but I still have a problem, this way the channel will close before receiving a message, this message is published in publishing, or the message will never reach subscribe, because when it is sent it won't be listening.

Comment: If the published message is received before the channel is read from, then the writer side of `ch` will block until it is ready to be read. It will not lose a message.

Comment: and how would I be able to stop the routine when receiving a value from the channel?

Comment: The goroutine will block until a value is written to the channel.

Comment: this code worked, but if you are being lucky, for example:
there are times that when I run I can get a message, ok := <- ch and then do a
assert.Equal(t, tt.want, message), but there are times when I don't get the msg on the channel and the test ends.

Comment: In that case, there is another race condition in your program that we cannot see here, or there is an error condition. The code here is sound. Try to print out the values of the state variables when you don't get the message. Maybe ch is closed?

Comment: from what I understand the race is in:

you're not yet subscribed to the thread and posted the event, and then subscribe to the topic.

Comment: With the addition of  the `subscribed` channel, it is guaranteed that the subscription is in place before the event is published.

Comment: I have another function that uses goroutine, (the function that reads the messages that are received in the topic channel, and in the new subscripts channel).could that be the reason?
but from what I debugged there are times that the subcribe is being paralleled with the publish

Comment: I will create a new question with more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383884/golang-goroutines-race-condition-in-test